# Improving a CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, webkit

I am in the process of incorporating an animated assistant in a Phonegap app for Android.  The idea is that a "smiley" taps on the phone screen for attention prior to doing other stuff.  I am something of a newbie at animations but with a spot of reading I managed to create something that roughly resembles what I want to accomplish - [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmx9tsf8/). However, I am far from satisfied with the smoothness of the end result and am wondering if I am not going about it the wrong way.

The CSS I have used is reproduced below

```
.mascot
{
 width:0;
 left:40vw;
 top:calc(50vh - 7vw);
 -webkit-animation:taptap 4s 1;
 position:absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes taptap
{
 0% {width:10vw;left:40vw;top:calc(50vh - 3.5vw;);}
 12.5% {width:20vw;left:40vw;top:calc(50vh - 7vw;);}
 25% {width:10vw;left:40vw;top:calc(50vh - 3.5vw;);}
 37.5% {width:20vw;left:40vw;top:calc(50vh - 7vw;);}
 50% {width:10vw;left:40vw;top:calc(50vh - 3.5vw;);}
 62.5% {width:20vw;left:40vw;top:calc(50vh - 7vw;);}
 75% {width:10vw;left:40vw;top:calc(50vh - 3.5vw;);}
 87.5% {width:20vw;left:40vw;top:calc(50vh - 7vw;);}
 99% {width:10vw;left:40vw;top:calc(50vh - 3.5vw;);}
 100%{width:0;}
}
```

A few notes are in order

- The original "mascot" image is roughly 200px(W) x 140px(H)
- I want this image to appear centered on the screen - irrespective of its size
- I do a spot of CSS `calc` to ensure that this happens in the vertical direction
- I do this by displacing the top of the image by half its height (in vw units) from the screen center which I establish as `50vh`
- `vw` as opposed to `vh` is used here to stop the image from being displaced incorrectly given that `1vh != 1vw` on most screens.
- Finally, I am assuming that if I provide the width the image will scale automatically and acquire the "correct" height

I'd be most obliged to anyone - who understands CSS animations better than I -  who might be able to suggest alterations to yield a smoother end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option, using `transform: scale`

*Don't forget to add back any prefix needed, to support the browsers of your choice*

```css
.mascot {
  width: 40vw;
  height: auto;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: taptap 4s forwards;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes taptap {
  0%,
  25%,
  50%,
  75%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
  12.5%,
  37.5%,
  62.5%,
  87.5% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src='data:image/png;base64,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'
class='mascot' />
```

Comment: Thank you - this is a whole lot smoother than my own effort.  There is just one issue - the data URI image I had provided is indeed 200 x 140 px in size.  However, eventually I had planned on using a larger image and viewport units to make the animation look "good" on different screen sizes - remembr this is for a Phonegap app so screen sizes vary wildly.  Will your solution not constrain the image to a fixed size?  That apart - any explanation on why your solution works so much better would be really useful.

Comment: @DroidOS Updated my answer with viewport units on the image. Using `transform` is the key to make it look smooth, and in this case it scale from its center origin.